# node red and host database connection

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, node-red

I try to learn Node Red at windows . I get some problems with my sql connection , database located in my site host at phpmyadmin ,(database is not in local host ) I don't know what is the host and port at setting of mysql node at node red . please help me to improve that , thank you

Comment: Do your database have remote connection ? And what's the error you are getting  and the port depends on the type of SQL you use

Comment: We can't tell you what the hostname and port number is for your database. You will need to ask your hosting provider.

Comment: It may also be the case that your database is not exposed so you can not directly connect to it remotely for security reasons.

Comment: phpMyAdmin is not a host, it's simply an administrative interface that helps with managing a MySQL or MariaDB installation. However, your connection information should be shown on the main phpMyAdmin page, there's an information box towards the right side of the initial page, but that only shows the connection _from the webserver_, if you're accessing from home then what hardillb said is true and you're probably blocked on port 3306 from outside the host's network. You'll either need a tunnel or API to connect from outside the network.